# How can I solve this differential equation in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

The differential equation is:

```
k*r=sqrt( (r`)^2 + r^2 )
```

The value of k is 2. How can I realize the function and solve it with ode45?

Comment: at least proofread your question.

Comment: nothing. I dont know how to make the function. I dont know how to write in matlab r`.

Comment: I'd start with reading an intro to matlab and `doc ode45`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward.  A few important things:

1. You need to express your differential equation in the format that ODE45 expects, which is `dy/dt = f(t,y)`.  That means that for your function, rather than `k*r=sqrt( (drdt)^2 + r^2 )`, you need to consider this as `drdt = sqrt(  (k*r)^2  -  r^2  )`  (assumming that I did my algebra correctly).
2. The function needs to be vectorizable.  For this problem, that pretty much means that instead of `^`, use `.^`, and instead of `*`, use `.*`.

Then we can use basic anonymous function syntax to setup the function to be solved:

```
k = 2;
fn_drdt = @(t,r) sqrt( (k.*r).^2 - (r.^2)  );
```

Use ODE45 to solve it

```
tStart = 0;
tEnd = 10;
r_init = -5;
[t, r] = ode45(fn_drdt, [tStart tEnd], r_init);
```

And then make a basic plot

```
plot(t,r,'.');
```

And add a title

```
title(sprintf('Solution to %s with k=%d ,r_0=%d', func2str(fn_drdt), k, r_init), 'fontname','courier')
```

Comment: `title(sprintf('Solution to %s with k=%d ,r_0=%d', func2str(fn_drdt), k, r_init), 'fontname','courier')`

Comment: How can i go through on this curve with a little circle?

Comment: i tried this but dont works:for i=0:0.1:length(t)
    plot(i,r(i),'ro');
    pause(0.02);
end

Comment: @EitanT, that is better.  I folded it into the answer.

Comment: @user1839790 "How to animate a plot" may be an interesting discussion for a separate question; or see if a few of these give you ideas:  http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=[matlab]%20animate%20plot .

Comment: @Pursuit No problem. Have a +1 for the unappreciated effort :)

Comment: If this were me, guys, I wouldn't have answered the question. The poster has made zero attempt at answering his question. This was a dump for homework help and you gave it to him. It is unlikely the poster has actually learned anything from your answer.

Comment: I don't know.  The question was specific and answerable, and I could answer it almost as fast as I could find another answer. (FWIW, the closest existing answer is probably: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691692/solving-an-ode-using-matlab/3691794#3691794, although I like mine better, probably because it sounds like me).  This seems to fall within the "go ahead and answer if you can" category described here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81693.